# Attempting to run program with Linked Lists and receiving "Segmentation Fault 11"

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

i'm currently trying to wrote a program that reads a file, taking in the first number (which will indicate how many lines there are in the file), then using linked lists, assign the values to nodes (structs). After assigning them, the program will print the results.
However, when running the program it outputs "Segmentation fault 11".
Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
            int day;
            int month;
            int year;
            char info[100];
            struct node *next;
};

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
      FILE* inFile = fopen(argv[2], "r");
      int checking, amount, i;


      checking = fscanf(inFile, "%d\n", &amount);
      if (checking != 1)
      {
              printf("Error reading the 1st line");
      }
      int amountupdated = (amount-1)/2;

      typedef struct node NODE;

      NODE *head, *first, *temp, *current, *previous = 0;
      head = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

      current = head;
      previous = NULL;
      for(i=0; i<amountupdated; i++)
      {
              fscanf(inFile, "%d%d%d\n", &current->day, &current->month, &current->year);
              fgets(current->info, 100, inFile);
              printf("%d-%d-%d: %s", current->year, current->month, current->day, current->info);
              previous = current;
              current = (*current).next;
      }
}
```

Could someone please explain to me where my memory fault is.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That means your program crashed. Probably because an invalid pointer. Use a debugger to find out where in your program the crash happened, and make sure all pointers are handled properly. I also recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: A hint though: In the loop where you read the input, where do `current->next` (or `(*current).next` as you write) actually point?

Comment: 1) Check return value of `fopen`. 2) You need to allocate each node.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
          current = (*current).next;
```

make no sense at all, you only ever allocate a single node, but seem to expect the program to be able to iterate over more than one. Instead you get undefined behavior since you're following uninitialized pointers.

You're going to have to call `malloc()` once for each node that you need to allocate, and link them all up.

By the way, `(*current).next` is more typically written `current->next`.